# Atwood Machine inside Elevator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, weight

[image]

Suppose we have a system as shown in the diagram above, inside an elevator, where object $Q$ has mass $M$, object $P$ has mass $m$, and $M>m$.

When this elevator accelerates upward with acceleration $a$, is it correct to say that in the frame of reference of the elevator, the forces $p$ and $q$ are $m(a+g)$ and $M(a+g)$ respectively?

If so, and if I assume that $Q$ moves downward with acceleration $f$ as observed from inside the elevator, can I say $M(a+g)-T=Mf$?

Or should I just say $Mg-T=Mf$, as they do in [this video](https://youtu.be/Jr6eg_36tno)? Why? How is it that the upward acceleration of the elevator has got no effect in this equation?

Comment: Your reasonning looks fine to me. Applying this to both masses leads to $f=\frac{M-m}{M+m}(a+g)$ and $T=\frac{Mm}{M+m}(a+g)$, which seems to behave correctly. Didnt watch the video though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a still from the video and in this case the term absolute in the context of the acceleration means **magnitude** relative to the ground.

[image]

Applying Newton's second law in the ground frame of reference for each of the masses with up as positive:

$T-6g = 6(b+\frac g8)$ and $T - 7g = 7(\frac g8 -b)$

and with two equations you can solve for the two unknowns $T$ and $b$.

Notice that in the video up is positive fro the left hand mass and down is positive for the right hand mass which I prefer not to do.
The two equations are essentially the same because mutiplying my second equation by $-1$ produces the lecturer's second equation.

Now let me rearrange my two equations by putting the term which contains $\frac 98$ on the left hand side.

$T-6g-6\frac g8 = T-6(g+\frac g8) = 6b$ and $T-7g-7\frac g8 = T-7(g+\frac g8) = 7(-b)$

Now these two equations are Newton's second law applied in the accelerating frame of the lift with two fictitious/pseudo force equal to $6\frac g8$ and $7\frac g8$ added to the masses.

Another way of looking at this is to say that the (local = relative to the lift) acceleration of free fall is $g+\frac g8$ downwards.

If the lift was accelerating downwards at $\frac g8$ then all that would happen is that there would be a change of sign for the fictitious/pseudo force.

$T-6g+6\frac g8 = T-6(g-\frac g8) = 6b$ and $T-7g+7\frac g8 = T-7(g-\frac g8) = 7(-b)$

This is perhaps what you might expect in that if the lift is accelerating downwards at $g$ then you find that both the tension $T$ is zero and the acceleration of the masses relative to the lift is also zero.